# unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' could not find it

Tags: php

While trying to do something like:

```
echo "<span>" "<b>" . $row["info1"] . "</b>" . $row["update1"] ."</span>";
```

It fails with an error log:

> unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: I'd advocate learning the difference between single and double quotes for strings in PHP. In the above, single quotes would actually make much more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre mising "." between `"<span>"` and `"<b>"`. Change your code like this

```
 echo "<span><b>" . $row["info1"] . "</b>" . $row["update1"] ."</span>";
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but btw how to make between both of them espace ?

Comment: Can you update the script with space between them , thanks

Comment: U mean this ` echo "<span><b>" . $row["info1"] . " </b>" . $row["update1"] ."</span>";` print with an space between  `$row["info1"]` and `$row["update1"]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to concate it properly http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
echo "<span><b> ".$row["info1"]."</b> ".$row["update1"]."</span>";
```

If you have multiple values to print then try this

```
$str = '<span>';
foreach($row as $val){
    $str .= '<b> '.$val.'</b>';
}
$str .= '</span>';
echo $str;
```

Comment: Don't use a non-breaking space in this context. Use them if you actually need them.

Comment: Yes it needed, I have read one comment 'Can you update the script with space between them' that's why I added this

Comment: @DsRaj What s/he meant was just use a regular space. No need to use `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Updated